# Definition of congruence of triangles.

Tags: geometry, congruences-geometry

In school level geometry,we studied congruence of triangles.Where it is defined that two triangles are congruent if they have same shape and size.But this is not a precise definition,what does it mean mathematically.I know some criteria for congruence which are $SSS,SAS,ASA,AAS,RHS$ criteria.But which one should I take as definition.Which one is the standard definition?

Comment: Two triangles are *defined* to be congruent if all six corresponding parts are congruent; that is, $\triangle ABC\cong\triangle A'B'C'$ when $\overline{AB}\cong\overline{A'B'}$, $\overline{BC}\cong\overline{B'C'}$, $\overline{CA}\cong\overline{C'A'}$, and $\angle A\cong\angle A'$, $\angle B\cong\angle B'$, $\angle C\cong\angle C'$. The patterns SAS, SSS, ASA, etc, (one of which is an *axiom*; the others, *theorems*) allow us to cheat a bit and *declare* two triangles to be fully congruent when we know only three congruences among the parts, so that we get the other congruences "for free".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One fairly typical text, Geometry by Moise & Downs, takes SAS as a postulate and proves all the others.

It might be interesting to note that two triangles can have 5 of the six parts congruent and yet not be congruent themselves.